# C# how to permute list values between keys?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, key, permutation

I have a Dictionary with multiple number of keys and multiple number of values by key.
I need to get all combinations of values bettwen keys.

exemple

key 1 values A,B

key 2 values X,Y

...

I need to get :

A,X

A,Y

B,X

B,Y
...

Any ideas for how to do this with C#?

Comment: How about you show us some code and what you have already tried? Did you try to search for an existing solution?

Comment: Arent you missing the combination ``A,B`` and what about ``B,A``? Maybe this helps https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Permutations.cs

Comment: I want to permute the values between keys and not values with same key so A,B and B,A are not solutions for this problem.

Comment: Please untag my question as a duplication of another completly different question .